# Forgotten iPad passcode - How to reset it with no access to old email address and without using iTunes?

Tags: ios, ipad, password

At first we forgot the passcode for our iPad, so we tried to change the passcode but it was connected to an old email address we no longer use.

The iPad is now disabled.

How do we reset it totally without using iTunes?

Comment: Anysha Goode, Please have a look at: [If you forgot the passcode for your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, or your device is disabled](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306) and if none of that is helpful, then take your device to an Apple store with your receipt.